# Gitlab can't clone/pull/push via command

Tags: git, gitlab

I have set up a Gitlab server by myself. it worked by command and by website. After I reconfigure the email to my smtp email server(originally not set any email server), I can't push/pull even clone by command. (it works with webpage, I can browse, edit and commit, push with webpage) 
The command line errors show as follows:

```
$ git clone http://192.168.xx.xx:9000/gitlab/root/xxxx.git
Cloning into 'xxxx'...
Username for 'http://192.168.xx.xx:9000': root
remote: Internal server error
fatal: unable to access 'http://192.168.xx.xx:9000/gitlab/root/xxxx.git/': 
The requested URL returned error: 500
```

Can anyone help? thanks!

Comment: Since it says 'Internal server error' and error 500, there should be more information in the production log at `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log` (assuming Omnibus package install). Please share any errors you see there.

Comment: yes. Finally, I found error show it need write permission for /var/opt/gitlab, then chmod a+w, it works.